# Detecting bad blocks/ sectors on modern (spinning) drives and script to monitor SMART info

Tags: bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I'm currently scanning a number of old drives to detect errors.

If you google detecting bad sectors on a mechanical spinning disk (rather than ssd) you'll usually come across:

windows

```
chkdsk/r drive:
```

linux (possibly different arguments

```
badblocks -wsv /dev/drive > file
```

and then to pass that file to the file system so as not to use those blocks.

But a modern hard drive will keep a certain amount of free to automatically reallocate these.

So am I right in saying that, if the disk is doing it's job, these bad blocks won't show up in the badblocks or chkdsk tests anyway as they'll be reallocated. The tests still serve a purpose in identifying the blocks to the drive but won't really show anything helpful until it's run out of sectors to reallocate.

You should really be keeping an eye on reallocated sectors in the SMART information for the drive.

But is there any way to know:

1. How many spare sectors the drive is keeping back for this reallocation
2. Similarly, how many reallocations is acceptable. I guess you're looking for a rate of increase here to show problems?
3. If you were scripting some monitoring of the reallocations, how you'd set those parameters.

Or have I missed the point here?

TL;DR Given that a drive will run out of reallocated sectors at some point. How would you script to send warnings when this occurs to allow you to start telling the file system to take account of bad blocks (assuming that the rate of change wasn't enough to indicate a significant failure).

Comment: If you are scripting you should read the SMART information and compare it to acceptable/unacceptable values (you can get the thresholds on the internet). It might be a good idea to monitor all essential SMART values not only the sector reallocation - depending on what you want to achieve. Some of those values might be model specific but I'm not completely sure about it.

Comment: thanks, was unaware of the thresholds so will look further (better!) cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> (How do you find out) How many spare sectors the drive is keeping back for this reallocation?

I'm not aware of any standard way to do this for spinning-platter drives.

In practice, it doesn't matter. If a spinning-platter hard disk develops more than a few grown defects, it is probably failing catastrophically, and no number of spare sectors could save it.

(SSDs have very different failure modes -- the use of spare capacity is normal aging behavior. They often expose this value as the Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk SMART parameter.)

> Similarly, how many reallocations is acceptable.

Zero, or at most perhaps 1-10. Any more is usually a sign of impending failure.

Comment: Wanted to keep questions short but I'm looking at some old drives for a hackspace and it's a case of 'shall we run them for a bit until they die, non critical data' - for myself/ good data I'd just get new.

Going to edit my question slightly.

Just to check - 1-10 % or RAW. As I've certainly had more than 10 in drives with no subsequent failure after months of running them. 

I think rate of increase is important for sure 

(Thanks for the mention of SSD as that will come up)

Answer (score 0):

```
How many spare sectors the drive is keeping back for this reallocation?
```

I have observed between 100-300, and I imagine a 10tb probably has 1000 or so.

```
Similarly, how many reallocations is acceptable. I guess you're looking for a rate of increase here to show problems?
```

Its not a good idea to have more than a few, but when all the spare sectors are used up dire SMART errors are reported by the BIOS.

The problem is bad blocks **should not** be visible to the file system, because SMART is supposed to cause the hard drive to consume a spare sector that the hard drive manufacturer provides.  These sectors are not visible to the file system.

However, SMART function doesn't always seem to be doing its job, I have observed many hard drives which simply refuse to take bad sectors out of service.  Even though I have tried with SpinRite and mhdd.

I don't know why this is, but if the hard drive manufacturer can avoid running out before the warranty runs out they don't have to replace it.  So its not in their best interest to use up the spare sectors.